# Sinch Video App Issue

Tags: android, sinch

I have installed sinch video calling app example in two of my device. One is Android Marshmallow (Nexus) and another one is Android KK (Samsung S4 mini). Now when i execute app on devices and try to place a video call now on the calling phone i can see my own video and not the recipients video.

in the layout that is supposed to show other user video is completely black .

Please guide how to remedy this problem.

Thanks

Comment: which library you used?

Comment: https://www.sinch.com/   sinch lib

Comment: try AppRTC for video calling

Comment: Please check for permissions, you might missed permission in Marshmallow device.

Comment: Hi RRR
This is not the issue only with my app.. Also it is the issue with sample provide with Sinch library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who encounters this problem. The problem is that Sinch requires you to show the local video view in order to transmit the stream. i.e., you will need to add BOTH local and remote views to your activity. If you don't add the local view, the remote view always stays black. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368512/sinch-video-chat-remote-video-issue).