# Sinch Video Chat - Remote Video Issue

Tags: android, sinch, videochat

I am developing a chat application. For the video chat integration i am using sinch android sdk. I got it https://github.com/sinch/android-video-calling sample working fine. I dont want to show local video view on user screen. So when i removed it from callscreen activity layout and from callscreen activity java class there is no remote video shown on either of the devices. The video views doesnt seem to be linked to view in layout as they are fetched from getSinchServiceInterface().getVideoController(). Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats right, right now you need a local view to transmit video, we are working on removing that. But for now you can add it and hide it to get it working for you.

Comment: Ok sir thank you for your reply. i actually tried to hide the view by setting its visibility parameter but it didnt work out.

Comment: hmm, try to move it out of sight then, let me know if that works.

Comment: Ok so i pushed the local view off the screen by setting the width and height parameters of remote view to match parent and the by changing their parent view to linearlayout. and it worked. Just tell me one thing more. Will this off screen thing have any effect on overall performance of the app?

Comment: It shoudlnt, and this quarter we will remove this requirement

Comment: the sinch video call example that comes within the sdk is not working for me. local video is displayed but remote is blank/black

Comment: made an issue about it on github: https://github.com/sinch/android-video-calling/issues/20