# Remote view of sinch library showing black area on addin view

Tags: android, sinch

In my app, I am implementing video chat and for that I am using sinch client and I am reffering below link provided by official documentation.

```
https://www.sinch.com/docs/video/android/#videocalling
```

and using below code i am adding remote view to the layout

```
 @Override
    public void onVideoTrackAdded(Call call) {
        Log.e("test","video track added is called now");
        SinchClient sinchClient = getSinchServiceInterface().getSinchClient();
        if (sinchClient != null) {
            VideoController videoController =  sinchClient.getVideoController();

            View myPreview = videoController.getLocalView();
            View remoteView = videoController.getRemoteView();
            mUpperLinearLayout.addView(myPreview);
            mLowerLinearLayout.addView(remoteView);
        }
    }
```

I have splitted out my UI into two linear layouts name upper layout and lower layout and I am adding remote view to the linear layout as mentioned in the documents. But I am getting black or blank view on connecting video call successfully.Why is that so am I missing anything?one more thing I have observed in log cat there is an error as mentioned below

```
 CameraEnumerator: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
```

I have googled a lot and tried different links as mentioned below

[Sinch Video Chat - Remote Video Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40368512/sinch-video-chat-remote-video-issue)

but no luck . Any help?

I am using below code for permission.

```
 private void callVideo() {
    try {
        Call call = getSinchServiceInterface().callVideoUser(mVoipContact.getUserName());
        if (call == null) {
            // Service failed for some reason, show a Toast and abort
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.txt_service_not_started) + getString(R.string.txt_placing_call), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        String callId = call.getCallId();
        Intent callScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), VideoCallScreenActivity.class);
        callScreen.putExtra(VoipConstants.CALL_ID, callId);
        startActivity(callScreen);
    } catch (MissingPermissionException e) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MessagingActivity.this, new String[]{e.getRequiredPermission()}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_CALL);
    }
}
```

Now i can see below log cat error

```
VideoCapturerAndroid: Camera freezed: Camera failure.
```

Comment: Why isn't your fyp over yet?

Comment: Sorry I did not get you

Comment: You once told that its your fyp and teachers were asking for some feature, so I thought its FYP

Comment: noi am on job now and it is the project feature and i am stuck very badly now

Comment: Okay, Do you have camera permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes i have camera permission in manifest as <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: and uses feature tag??

Comment: yes i do have as mentioned <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

Comment: The error you are getting is simply because your app isn't able to access the camera, it can be because the permission isn't allowed, can you show the code where it is trying to access the camera

Comment: any help or suggestion?

Comment: Yeah try asking for permission first then execute your code

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 50);
}    else {       


   callVideo(); 
}
```

For other error try adding this `setPreviewTexture()` in Try Catch **OR** just remove this line

Comment: tried that but now i can see in log as 
VideoCapturerAndroid: Camera freezed: Camera failure.

Comment: where to use setPreviewTexture() method?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding localView when remote view will be active. Try to add localView when sinch client is ready. In sinch if localView will not be clear then remote view will not show.

I don't know your code flow so I can't say where you have to add localView.

I hope, It will help you.